# Working with IBM Worklight and Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

I was working with Sencha 2.2.1 with Phonegap. Recently I heard about IBM Worklight and now I am trying to develop apps using Sencha + Worklight. But unfortunately I didn't get any helpful tutorial on using sencha touch 2.2.1 application with Worklight.

What iImean is, for PhoneGap, Adobe explains how to build a native app using that. But, in the case of Worklight I can't find any tutorials that explains about what should I do with a sencha app in my hand when converting to android apk or iOS with using Worklight.

I got a sample project from IBM's site. But I didn't understand anything about the topic from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. :)

What my problem was, I was having a Sencha Touch 2.2.1 project in my hand, and I need to build the **Android apk**  installation file of the same. I was not knowing how to handle the MVC structure of Sencha inside Worklight. But finally I figured out it. The entire process I did is as follows:

- *build* my Sencha Touch 2.2.1 Project
- In my **Eclipse Java EE IDE** ( i used  **Kepler Eclipse**) , I created a new  **Worklight Project** . Chose  *Hybrid Application* as *Project Template*.
- Then I copied all the files created when I build my Sencha app. (  *resources folder, app.js, app.json, cordova.js, index.html* ) to the **common** folder inside my Worklight project I created.
- Initially there will be an  *index.html*  file inside the *common* folder. Overwrite that with our Sencha app's *index.html*
- Then create a new  *Worklight Environment*
- Choose the Worklight project we created and corresponding Application name.
- Check the *Android phones and tablets* option from the Create folders for section.
- Now you can see an Android project named as *Worklight_project_name+Application_name+Android* in the Project explorer.
- Right click on that project and choose  Run As -> Android Application . Then choose your emulator. ( I run it on my Android mobile ).
- Hurray !! You could see it as working..!! :)

I found out that the MVC structure of Sencha in not a problem anymore..!

Hope it helps someone else..! :)

NOTE: If you are using **CORDOVA** features inside your hybrid application, while overwriting **index.html** don't forget to add the following lines of code inside your **index.html** file:

```
<script src="worklight/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="worklight/wljq.js"></script>
<script src="worklight/worklight.js"></script>
<script src="worklight/checksum.js"></script>
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
```